# How to make class such that properties will not be able to change

Tags: c#

Let supppose that we have simple class as below:

```
public class Foo
{
    public List<int> l { get; set; }

    public Foo(List<int> newList)
    {
        this.l = newList;
    }
}
```

now we can use it:

```
    List<int> l = new List<int>() { 1, 2 };
    Foo foo = new Foo(l);

    foreach (int i in foo.l)
        Console.WriteLine(i);
```

Of course, on console we see

```
1
2
```

But if we change list `l`:

```
    l[0] = 11;
    l[1] = 22;
```

and invoke loop again:

```
foreach (int i in foo.l)
    Console.WriteLine(i);
```

we have on console

```
11
22
```

Thus, the list in foo class is changed. Is there any possibility in C#, to see on console again

```
1
2
```

so make class Foo such that, the list will be never changed ?

Comment: Implement `IReadOnlyList<T> Interface`.

Comment: @JenniferS this will prevent the list changes not list elements.

Comment: Getting rid of the public setter would be a good start.

Answer (score 3):

You can copy the input list, make the setter private and expose an `IReadOnlyList<T>`:

```
public class Foo
{
    public IReadOnlyList<int> l { get; private set; }

    public Foo(IEnumerable<int> newList)
    {
        this.l = new ReadOnlyCollection<int>(newList.ToList());
    }
}
```

Comment: One suggestion would be to change the constructor-argument-type from `List<int>` to `IEnumerable<int>`.

Answer (score 3):

First things first: this is C# and you cannot protect your code against malicious misuse. You can however, make it user-friendly by making it difficult to misuse. For example by using the interface that fulfills all criteria... and not more:

```
public class Foo
{
    public IEnumerable<int> Numbers { get; private set; }

    public Foo(IEnumerable<int> numbers)
    {
        this.Numbers  = numbers;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not correct - If you give the constructor a list, then you can still alter the contents of the enumerable-that-is-exposed-from-Foo.

Comment: Mine answer would have be a slight variation on yours, but not exposing concrete implementations like List<int> was a fundamental when I was learning

Comment: Not to mention that you can no longer do foo.l[3] for example.

Comment: @decPL that may be a good thing, there's a reason enumerators are useful. If that was desired an indexed property is a simple way forward.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I'm by no means saying enumerators aren't useful (being a major LINQ fan that'd be strange for me). I'm just saying that this answer, while not fixing the problem mentioned in the question (as Maarten noted), changes the original class's member type without knowing how it is used. I do believe in always exposing the most low-level type possible in .NET, but without any info about what the author is doing with his class, we can't make such a decision for him.

Comment: @decPL, indeed not, completely agree. With publicly available setter, changing the content of the list is near a moot point. :(

Comment: This can't solve the problem. The `IEnumerable<int>` can be easily cast to `List<int>` if underlying type is suitable.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Yes it can. It can also manipulated in a thousand others ways. This is what I wanted to express with my first sentence. You cannot make this secure. It's just not possible. `System.Reflection` or simply `void*` and everything you wrote is circumvented.

Comment: The term `secure` isn't absolute. The question how much is it secure.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan From my point of view, casting something to a different type because you *know* it is this type is such a grave breach of developer etiquette, that it's already on the *malicious* side of bad software development practices.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Foo
{
    private List<int> _l;

    public IList<int> L { get { return this._l.AsReadOnly(); } }

    public Foo(List<int> newList)
    {
        this._l = new List<int>(newList);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could dress your private variable with a readonly property, or not include the "set" action on your property.

What you actually need is this option #1 or #2

## 1

```
private readonly List<int> _l;
public List<int> l { get; set; }
```

## 2

```
public List<int> l { get; }
```

[MSDN readonly prop link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7.aspx)

Comment: Not correct - The question is about the **contents** of the list, not about the list-object itself. And option 2 doesn't compile.